# 415 (Unsupported Media Type) with REST Post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a react component that when a checkbox is pressed, it calls a rest api, post request with a single parameter.

I put a breakpoint in the webapi and its never hit, still I get a 415 unsopported media type on the component

```
react js component (see onchange event)

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  Table, Radio} from 'antd';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';
import Notification from '../../components/notification';

class ListTenants extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    }



    fetchData = () => {
        adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Tenant", {})
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
            if (!this.isCancelled) {
                const results= responseJson.map(row => ({
                    key: row.ClientId,
                    ClientId: row.ClientId,
                    ClientSecret: row.ClientSecret,
                    Id: row.Id,
                    SiteCollectionTestUrl: row.SiteCollectionTestUrl,
                    TenantDomainUrl: row.TenantDomainUrl
                  }))
              this.setState({ data: results });
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };


    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }

    render() {
        const columns = [
                {
                    title: 'Client Id',
                    dataIndex: 'ClientId',
                    key: 'ClientId'
                }, 
                {
                    title: 'Site Collection TestUrl',
                    dataIndex: 'SiteCollectionTestUrl',
                    key: 'SiteCollectionTestUrl',
                },
                {
                    title: 'Tenant DomainUrl',
                    dataIndex: 'TenantDomainUrl',
                    key: 'TenantDomainUrl',
                }
        ];

        // rowSelection object indicates the need for row selection
        const rowSelection = {
            onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
                if(selectedRows[0].key != undefined){
                    console.log(selectedRows[0].key);


                    const options = { 
                        method: 'post', 
                        body: JSON.stringify({ clientid : selectedRows[0].key.toString() }) ,
                        config: {
                            headers: {
                              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            }
                          }
                    };

                    adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Tenant/SetTenantActive", options)
                        .then(response =>{
                        if(response.status === 200){
                            Notification(
                                'success',
                                'Tenant set to active',
                                ''
                                );
                        }else{
                            throw "error";
                        }
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                        Notification(
                            'error',
                            'Tenant not activated',
                            error
                            );
                        console.error(error);
                    });
                }
            },
            getCheckboxProps: record => ({
                type: Radio
            }),
        };

        return (
            <Table rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.data} />
        );
    }
}

export default ListTenants;
```

and the webapi method

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("api/Tenant/SetTenantActive")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SetTenantActive([FromBody]string clientid)
        {
            var tenantStore = CosmosStoreFactory.CreateForEntity<Tenant>();
            var allTenants = await tenantStore.Query().Where(x => x.TenantDomainUrl != null).ToListAsync();
            foreach(Tenant ten  in allTenants)
            {
                ten.Active = false;
                await tenantStore.UpdateAsync(ten);
            }

            var tenant = await tenantStore.Query().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.clientid == clientid);
            if (tenant == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            tenant.Active = true;
            var result = await tenantStore.UpdateAsync(tenant);

            return Ok(result);
        }
```

Comment: Press F12, go to network log, do the request, check open the request look for the Content-Type parameter in the request, then look down in the bottom what the payload is

Comment: https://screencast.com/t/rGmbacnPJ

Comment: open the Request Headers, that's where the media type is specified

Comment: https://screencast.com/t/YB6b9D0LJkS

Comment: Your Content-Type is text/plain; charset=utf-8, which is technically correct, but the server is probably expecting application/json; charset=utf-8. I see that adalFetch doesn't set the content type with `config.contentType`

Comment: yes I am adding this: 
                    const options = { 
                        method: 'post', 
                        body: JSON.stringify({ clientid : selectedRows[0].key.toString() }) ,
                        config: {
                            headers: {
                              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            }
                          }
                    };

Comment: Give me two seconds, its very hard to google for adal, but i have a feeling that headers should not be inside config, but right below options

Comment: If it does not hit webapi, it could be rejected before. Any router front of? (like nginx)

Comment: its this library I am using https://github.com/salvoravida/react-adal

Comment: Have you tried w/o the FomBody attribute?

Comment: yes I did that also

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Couple of things I noticed.

1. You're trying to do a `POST` request with a JSON body. On the client, your request looks fine.

As I understand the POST body is

```
{ clientid: 'some-client-id' }
```

2. The interesting thing is in the web API you receive it as

`public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SetTenantActive([FromBody]string clientid)`

This is possibly the culprit. Your API is expecting a string as a POST body where it is a json object. Have you tried changing the type to `dynamic` or `JObject`?

So, essentially,

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SetTenantActive([FromBody]dynamic clientRequest)
```

OR

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SetTenantActive([FromBody]JObject clientRequest)
```

**Alternately,**

If you want to continue using your API as is, then you can just change the request you’re making from the client to `’some-client-id’` instead of `{ clientid: 'some-client-id' }`

Comment: You are right, missed that completely. Alternatively the body could be set to `'some-client-id'` (including the quotes and keeping `application/json` as content-type), which will be deserialized to a simple string, so @Luis Valencia could go with his `post` endpoint. But this still doesn't explain the resulting status code.

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
const options = { 
    method: 'post', 
    body: JSON.stringify({ clientid : selectedRows[0].key.toString() }) ,
    config: {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
};
```

to

```
const options = { 
    method: 'post', 
    body: JSON.stringify({ clientid : selectedRows[0].key.toString() }) ,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your server settings. By default it should support `json` but its better to verify it. Also try to clear `Accept` header in yor api code and set to `*` which means all types.

Moreover check `adalApiFetch` method. What headers it send? Is the format of `Content-Type` used & set correctly?

Answer (score 1):

For a simple RESTFul call like that you could follow suggestion naming conventions along with HTTP verbs that better clarifies the intention and simplify the call itself. No need to over complicate the API model for such a simple call.

Something like

```
[HttpPut] // Or HttpPost. PUT is usually used to update the resourcce
[Route("api/Tenant/{clientid}/Active")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SetTenantActive(string clientid) {
    var tenantStore = CosmosStoreFactory.CreateForEntity<Tenant>();
    var allTenants = await tenantStore.Query().Where(x => x.TenantDomainUrl != null).ToListAsync();
    var updates = new List<Task>();
    foreach(Tenant ten  in allTenants) {
        ten.Active = false;
        updates.Add(tenantStore.UpdateAsync(ten));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(updates);

    var tenant = await tenantStore.Query().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.clientid == clientid);
    if (tenant == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    tenant.Active = true;
    var result = await tenantStore.UpdateAsync(tenant);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

And on the client

```
const rowSelection = {
    onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
        if(selectedRows[0].key != undefined){
            var clientid = selectedRows[0].key;
            console.log(clientid);

            var url = "/Tenant/" + clientid + "/Active"

            const options = { 
                method: 'put'
            };

            adalApiFetch(fetch, url, options)
                .then(response => {
                if(response.status === 200){
                    Notification(
                        'success',
                        'Tenant set to active',
                        ''
                        );
                }else{
                    throw "error";
                }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                Notification(
                    'error',
                    'Tenant not activated',
                    error
                    );
                console.error(error);
            });
        }
    },
    getCheckboxProps: record => ({
        type: Radio
    }),
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Why are you using `post`? From a 'REST`y point of view, it is used to create an entity (a tenant in your case).

The simple request intended can be solved via `GET` with the `clientid` as part of the route:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Tenant/SetTenantActive/{clientid}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SetTenantActive(string clientid)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I thought that get is only for read operations, settenantactive is an update operation on the DB

Comment: Your endpoint and intention doesn't fit into the standard 'REST'y samples (mostly CRUD stuff).You are updating an existing tenant, so you might use `PUT` or `PATCH` (which will probably lead to the same problem). But as you don't have a tenant-object with the intended new property values to pass via body, you might as well go along with a `GET`.